# Android: Need custom calendar like CKCalendar in iOS

Tags: android, android-calendar

I need custom calendar like CKCalendar in iOS - https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar

In CKCalendar iOS I can set colors of days, can disable dates for touch.

Is there anything similar for Android?

Comment: You need to create your custom calendar. default calendar doesnt provide disabling dates facility

Comment: @nubaslon what did you end up with? I've used Times Square before, but did you fine something closer to CKCalendar?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Times Square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) by Square. It might not have the exact customizations you want but it's customizable enough so that you can modify to suit your needs.